# Xcode 7 missing required architecture arm64 in file

Tags: ios, xcode

I started a new project and Added an SDK and got this warning:

```
ignoring file libLineaSDK.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file libLineaSDK.a (3 slices)
```

my question is how do I add the required architecture in Xcode 7...either blind because I dont see it.

**UPDATE**

I was able to find the architectures in build settings and I see arm64 is one of the listed artchitectures, so now I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing same problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recompile `libLineaSDK.a` with arm64 turned on. If it's a third-party library, you'll have to ask provider for a 64-bit compatible version.

Comment: how do I recomplie with arm64 turned on?

Comment: @user979331 if you have source code, you should add arm64 to it's architectures

Answer (score 0):

Use

> otool -hv /path/to/libLineaSDK.a

If your architecture is not among the listed, compile the lib again but for the respective architecture.

If the architecture is listed, check your library path, it may point to a different version.